# Using date list to filter image collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, filter, date

I have a CSV with a column of dates. I already imported the CSV, but I would like to know If I could use that column to filter an Image Collection.

Just now, I wrote all dates and used a filter to  exclude dates from the desired list of dates

```
var Class0Images = image_2.filter(ee.Filter.inList("system:time_start", F0Date));
```

However, non image was returned and I know there are dates in the list that could return images from the sentinel 1 image collection.

This is the link of my script, which I also computed polarimetric indexes:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/43144b99eb7c14dbdc9bd3953a59dc46

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are filtering the image on a simple time format, namely at 00:00 AM each day. The `system:time_start` property contain the exact sensing time. Therefore, first set a new date property to each image at 00:00AM:

```
// set a date property to exactly 00:00 AM
var image_2 = image_2.map(function(image){
  return image.set('simpleTime', ee.Date(image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd')).millis());
});
```

Then filter on that property:

```
//Applying date filter
var Class0Images = image_2.filter(ee.Filter.inList("simpleTime", F0Date)); 
print('filtered by simpleTime',Class0Images);
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/80995af0dcde59fcb0289cb25824f9f6), where unshared imports were removed.